# oracle developer_ importing different forms of date in one column

Tags: oracle, date

I am trying to import the date columns with different types of date format.

**table name**: fD (1604294 size of csv file)

**column name**: TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME

this column has two forms of the date like below.
**date type1**: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
**date type2**: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'

not surprisingly, SQL developer(oracle) cannot import this column as a DATE type.
I aim to unify these forms as 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI.'

What I did was I import it as a VARCHAR2 type and try to write very complicate and difficult(?) query...
and then I read someone wrote here that do not import date type data as a VARCHAR2 because of this. Then, is there any idea that I can import this column successfully? or I need to import it as a VARCHAR2 type and write down complicated query? (and I do not know this query either.. haha)

this is what I did when I imported it as a VARCHAR2.

```
with DT as(
select TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME from fD
)
select TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,
replace(to_char(to_date(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME, case 
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
when regexp_like(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') then 'MM/DD/yyyy HH24:MI'
end), 'MM/DD/yyyy HH24:MI'),'') as newT from DT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem so I am sharing what I did here! I imported the column as VARCHAR2 and then used this.

```
-- query test before updating table
select (case when instr(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , '-') > 1 then 
             to_char(to_date(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
        else to_char(to_date(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
        end) field_as_date 
 from fd;



-- update the table as 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' based on the test

UPDATE fd
SET TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME = case when instr(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , '-') > 1 then 
             to_char(to_date(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
        else to_char(to_date(TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
        end;



-- check if 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' row is transformed into 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'

select * from (select rownum as num, trans_date_trans_time from fd) a where a.num=1048680;
-- transformed!


-- check if there is null compared to the size of 1604294
select count(trans_date_trans_time)  from fd; 
--  => 1604294 (no null)
```

Thank you people who answered this post for me!

Answer (score 0):

How about simple two-step approach?

```
insert into target_table (column list goes here)
select ...,
       to_date(date_value_column, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
from source_table;
```

and then

```
insert into target_table (column list goes here)
select ...,
       to_date(date_value_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
from source_table;
```

Because, all rows - that don't fit specified date format - will be discarded in the 1st query and loaded with the 2nd one (and vice versa).

Comment: I am importing the data from csv file with 1604294 size of data, so I don't think I can list all in this... :(

Comment: CSV file: that sounds as if it could be source for an **external table**. If you do that, then you actually *can* write any query you want against it. I don't quite understand what you meant by saying that you can't "list all in this" - what does that mean?

Comment: it seems I do not understand when you say ' list goes here'. which list you mean?

Comment: Aha. List of columns in target table. For example: `insert into target_table (id, name, address, birth_date)`

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, just try to convert the value to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE` and include the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` option and then use `COALESCE` to try the different formats:

```sql
SELECT TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME,
       COALESCE(
         TO_DATE(
           TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'
         ),
         TO_DATE(
           TRANS_DATE_TRANS_TIME DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
         )
       ) as newT
FROM   DT;
```